# Facebook - Open Graph not detecting meta tags (Gatsby + Netlify)

Tags: gatsby, netlify, react-helmet, facebook-debugger

I deployed a blog using Gatsby + Netlify. I am currently using react-helmet to populate the proper meta tags on each blog post.

For some reason Facebook Open Graph is not detecting the meta tags that belong to the blog and it is defaulting to use the meta tags of the home page.

This is what I get from Facebook Debugger:

`The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id`

This is what I get when I click on - See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL:
`The document returned no data.`

Note: Netlify - I am not currently using Netlify prerender.

Gatsby, this an example of how the code handles meta tags on blog posts (Twitter tags work properly).

```
  {
    property: 'og:image',
    content: `https://website.com${image}`,
  },
```

I already tried refreshing Facebook Debugger (scrape again) with no luck.

Any ideas if this is an issue with Netlify, Facebook or Gatsby/react-helmet?

Comment: I just enabled Netlify prerender to see if it helps scraping from Facebook OG.

Comment: And did it help?

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely to be an issue with Netlify. Facebook's refreshing button usually works quite well.

It's most likely Gastby/ReactHelmet - have you opened up the compiled and hosted HTML on your site, via the Inspector or View Source? That's the best place to debug this kind of issue.